# Get numbers from string and except html entity numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract an ID, ('123456789' number below) from an URL.

For example this doesn't work:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/page-name%C3%A5rd/123456789

*Note '%C3%A5' in the URL.*

But this works:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/page-name/123456789

This is the PHP I am using:

```
    if (strpos($url,'pages') == true) {

    $page_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$url);

    }
```

Comment: Define what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Hehe, funny. No, That function catches all the numbers in the string, including `%C3%A5`, I only want the numbers `123456789`. So one number must be next to at least 3 numbers in the string.

Comment: Is the series of digits always at the end of the URL?

Comment: @Kim: "So one number must be next to at least 3 numbers in the string" --- and have you made a research on how to require some regex pattern to repeat N times?

Comment: @ajp15243 there may well be parameters on the facebook url.

Comment: @jdog True, although one could strip off everything after the first `?` (or `#` for hashes) before running it through the regex, but that's starting to be a more complex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
if (preg_match('#pages/[^/]+/(\d+)#',$url,$array)){
    $page_id = $array[1];
}
```

Explanation: I don't know exactly how Facebook urls work, but I assumed you are looking at a subset of urls - starting wih pages - and also that the numeric part is actually separated by the / character. This is in my opinion a better choice than looking for 3+ numbers, which is an arbitrary "reaction" to finding url encoded characters in the url.

I think you can't assume that there will be nothing after them, url parameters seem to be very common in social media sites.

Another thing is that # works in my experience in a wider range of real life urls as a regex "wrapping character", so I recommend to use this by default, not the / used in most examples. Further, when I started with regex, I would often try to cover a set of characters with .*? - any character, 0 or multiple times, non-greedy. I found that instead using the "not that character pattern", in this case [^/]+ (not a slash) works more reliably. You can use this to match html tags well: ]*> or attributes of html tags: ]*"[^"]*"[^>]*>